# Yes/No : Is $(X, \tau)$ is second countable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set $(\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N})\cup \{1 \} $. Define a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ by

$$
 f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x       & \quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N}  \\
    1  & \quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb{N}
  \end{cases}
$$

Further, define a topology on $\tau$ on $X$ by

$$
\tau = \{ U : U \subseteq X \text{ and } f^{-1}(U) \text{ is open in the euclidean topology on } \mathbb{R} \}
$$

Is  $(X, \tau)$ is second countable ?

My attempt :  I know that $(X, \tau )$ is first countable because here  every point $x$ in $X$ has a countable neighbourhood base.Take  $U$ be an open neighborhoods of $1$ in $X$ then $U=  ( \textstyle{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}} ( n-\varepsilon_n , n+\varepsilon_n) ) \cup ( \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 1 \} )$

Im confusing about that $(X, \tau)$ is second countable or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is not even first countable: specifically, it’s not first countable at $1$.

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be any countable family of open nbhds of $1$ in $X$. Then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a sequence $\left\langle\epsilon_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ of positive real numbers such that

$$\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\left(k-\epsilon_k^{(n)},k+\epsilon_k^{(n)}\right)\subseteq B_n\,.$$

Define a new sequence, $\langle\epsilon_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ by setting $\epsilon_k=\frac{\epsilon_k^{(k)}}2$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Let

$$U=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}(k-\epsilon_k,k+\epsilon_k)\,.$$

Show that $U$ is an open nbhd of $1$ that does not contain any member of $\mathscr{B}$ and hence that $\mathscr{B}$ cannot be a local base at $1$.